# Why do we have an intuition tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

Being subjective and rather vague, I propose that the intuition tag be done away with.

Answer (score 5):

Yes please. It's a meta tag, and a very vague one at that.

Once this gets consensus we'll see about getting it burninated.

Comment: Yes, most of the uses seem to be pretty bad questions.

Comment: @dmckee That too, I'll go through it and pick off any (unclosed, bad question) stragglers if they exist.

Comment: @dmckee I have looked at the 36 questions that have that tag, there are a few bad apples among them but most of them seem good conceptual questions and some are even very good and high level. However, I dont know if the tag is realy needed to characterize questions that seek a qualitative or intuitive understanding, maybe not ...?

Comment: I agree with removing the tag.

Comment: I agree with removing the tag as well. That you're looking for intuition (perhaps alongside a more mathematical answer) should almost be a given on here. Most of the questions on here need at least *some* intuition in the answers, and (nearly?) all of them could use it. Plus, it's always possible to state it in your question if you're mainly/only looking for intuition. No real need for a tag. You're always asking for intuition *about something*. That something is what the tags should represent.

Comment: @wouter exactly, well put :)

Comment: Agree with the above points - just because a tag has good questions doesn't mean it's a good tag. Though there are apparently 3 people who follow the tag...

Comment: The point that there are people following the tag should be taken into account and the reasonable non crappy usage @dimension10 suggests could be a good one. Why not remove it just from the bad questions (and close these), write an appropriate tag wiki along the lines dimension 10 suggests and thats it?

Comment: @dil possibly, though renaming it simultaneously would be good. However, the nea definition stil" applies to many, many questions imo.

Comment: @Manishearth Can this be treated as a green signal for removal of the tag or more votes are necessary?

Comment: @Prathyush IMO yes, because (a) it's a meta tag, and (b) this has enough votes. For that matter, (a) s enough to get it removed from the start. However, instead of manually removing it, I'll request burnination.